# I installed odoo-11.0 and when i started the server this message came to me

Tags: odoo

I installed Odoo-11.0 and when I run the server from the terminal this error shows:

```
ImportError: No module named 'ir_model'
```

Comment: Did you checked your addons path?

Comment: Hey you found any solution related to this problem ?